# Rails email attachments using the carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, email-attachments

I'm trying to allow a user to upload a file in a mailer form and send the attachment without having to save it onto the server.  I'm using rails 3, sqlite3, and carrierwave.  I thought I had everything set up correctly, but I recieve a `NoMethodError: undefined method`ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass`.  What am I doing wrong.

Here is my controller action:

def submit_eng

```
@request = Request.find(params[:id])
@email = params[:email]
@message = @email[:message]
@request = @request.eng_status(@request)
@subject = @email[:subject]
@additional_emails = @email[:recipient]
attachment = params[:attachment]
respond_to do |format|
  RequestMailer.submit_additional(@request, @message, @additional_emails, @subject, attachment).deliver if @additional_emails != ""

  @request.update_attributes(params[:request])
  format.html { redirect_to home_url, alert: "SIR has been submitted to engineering.  Please push up the revision level and resubmit if you make any changes." }
  format.json { render json: @requests }
end
```

end

Here is the submit_additional method in the mailer:

```
  def submit_additional(request, message, additionalemails, subject, attachment)
    @request = request
    @message = message
    @emails = additionalemails
    @subject = subject
    to = []
    to << @emails
    attachment[attachment.original_filename] = attachment.read()
    mail to: to, subject: 'SIR '+@request.request_number.to_s+' notification'+'  '+@subject, template_name: 'eng_notify'
  end
```

and lastly, here is the form that the user is filling out:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'submit_eng', :multipart => true, :id => @request.id) %>

<p><label for="email_subject">Additional Subject Notes</label>
<%= text_field 'email', 'subject' %></p>
<p><label for="email_recipient">Additional Recipients</label>
<%= text_field 'email', 'recipient' %></p>
<p><label for="email_attachment">Attachments</label></p>
<%= file_field_tag 'attachment' %>
<p><label for="email_message"></label><br/>
<%= text_area 'email', 'message', value: render('submit_eng.text.erb'), class: "span6" %></p>
<%= form_tag %>
```

The error itself shows like this pointing to the 'attachments[]' line in the mailer method:

```
NoMethodError in RequestsController#submit_eng

undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass

Application Trace
app/mailers/request_mailer.rb:11:in `submit_additional'
app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:138:in `block in submit_eng'
app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:137:in `submit_eng'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"R7h2RwuF0NYgoqfnm0k7/qNghcngXBNxznVt8sZGEH0=",
 "email"=>{"subject"=>"",
 "recipient"=>"asdf@gmail.com",
 "message"=>"All,
\r\n\r\nA new SIR has been created by asdf with the following details:\r\n\r\nSIR #: 5\r\nRequester: sabrams\r\nRegional Sales Manager: sabrams\r\nQuote Number: \r\nOrder Number: \r\nCustomer: \r\nCustomer Location: \r\nProduct Line: EMW\r\nInquiry Creation Date: 2014-10-08\r\nStatus: In Engineering\r\n\r\nGeneral Description: asdf\r\nAdditional Comments: \r\n\r\n\r\nPlease log onto the Engineering Database and add engineering lead time,
 hours,
 and any other relevant information,
 then submit the SIR to manufacturing.\r\n\r\nPlease contact asdf with any questions or comments."},
 "attachment"=>"test.jpg",
 "id"=>"5",
 "multipart"=>"true"}
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I deleted the comment because I saw that after the fact. ha. so I was going through it again. I read the first couple of lines and jumped to conclusions. Sorry about that. ha

Comment: No worries, I found out the error is coming from the file name part of the attachments line because it doesn't like the @ symbol, if I get rid of that and just type a generic filename in, the email sends, but the attachment itself is empty, so it's not uploading or handling the file correctly.

Comment: Yea I am looking around the carrier wave, read me. I actually just started messing with it the other week. Do you not have to call a .save! on it? Technically you still have to save the cache, right?

Comment: I don't. I didn't think I needed it since I wasn't actually going to save the file to the server. I'll try throwing that in before the call to the mailer and see if it has any effect.

Comment: Yea the gem says "Now you can cache files by assigning them to the attribute, they will automatically be stored when the record is saved." Also mine weren't saving the otherday because I didn't permit them. Since you mentioned rails 3, I guess adding them to the whitelist, so :attachment would be added. But I may be speaking too soon. Just what I went through the other day.